# MS Sql Server Pivot two columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I can not seem to find an example of this type of pivot if it is possible.

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
|      10 | A       |
|      20 | B       |
|      30 | C       |
+---------+---------+
```

I would like my query to return

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 30 |
+----+----+----+
```

I would like to do it without creating a view or dynamic table.

I have been trying the pivot option but I am having a problem understanding how to use dynamic values from the query. My query is:

```
 Select column1, column3 + '_' + column4 as column2 
 from table1
```

Now I want to use the column2 values as columns names with the associated column1 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select A, B, C
from yourtable
pivot
(
  max(column1)   -- column values
  for column2 in (A, B, C)  -- new column names
) p;
```

If you have dynamic columns then you will have to use dynamic SQL and implement it inside of a stored procedure. The code would be similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- create the list of columns for the pivot
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(column2) 
                    from 
                    (
                       select column3 + '_' + column4 as column2 
                       from table1
                     ) d
                     group by column2
                     order by column2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               Select column1, column3 + ''_'' + column4 as column2 
               from table1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(column1)
                for column2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: @user1088014 If you have dynamic values, then you'll need to use dynamic sql.  Are you planning on using a view for this or a stored procedure?  You won't be able to use dynamic sql in a view.

Comment: I was not planning on using either.  I do not have keys to the database so I am trying to work with only the sql.  So I think I hear you saying this can not be done with a pivot query.  The data is exam scoring and different exams have different numbers of sections.  Sections is the column2.

Comment: @user1088014 Yes it can be done, I've updated my answer to include a version of how to do it dynamically.

Comment: I meant can not be done without stored procedure or view. Thanks.

Comment: @user1088014 You can run it directly in SSMS but if you are trying to execute this inside your application, then you'll want to utilize code for that app.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when column2 = 'A' then column1 end as A,
       case when column2 = 'B' then column1 end as B,
       case when column2 = 'C' then column1 end as C
from your_table
```